# Read ENV variable value within the ENV File only

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I have an environment variable called ABCD in .ENV File. And Along with this, I have another env variable which is XYZ.

Let's assume this is my **example.env** file

```
ABCD=some_imp_value_which_is_variable
.
.
.
XYZ=testvalue.<value of ABCD>.xxxxx
.
.
```

In bash, If I want to read the value of ABCD, I would use `$ABCD` and store it to XYZ using `XYZ=testvalue.$ABCD.xxxxx`

```sh
ABCD=some_imp_value_which_is_variable
.
.
.
XYZ=testvalue.$ABCD.xxxxx
```

Do we have something similar to do in .env file. ABCD is variable value and we want XYZ to have the value based on ABCD.

**We are avoiding script (as that will require lots of changes to be done), So instead we want to do it in .env file itself**

Comment: A `.env` file by itself is just a text file, and has no behaviour, so the answer to this is going to depend on what you're using to _read_ that file.

Comment: We are using docker container to read the file. This is technically ENV vars for a specific container. But this ENV file comes from somewhere else. The value of XYZ is empty in beginning, and we can only pass value to it.

Comment: My opinion is .env files should always be handcrafted. Copy the contents as you need them and deploy the file on your desired system.

Comment: Plain `docker run --env-file` can't do this; it does no interpretation on the contents of the file.  Language-specific packages that read a `key=value` format file often can but it's not totally generic.

Comment: Thanks everyone, As I was unable to change anything to that env file, I end up reading whole Env file being received and creating another file based on it using script and then sending it to docker container.